# getText().toString().trim().length() == 4 not working

Tags: android

I am Checking if my EditText has text inside of it, i am using this code for that to work:

```
if (mSwitcher.getText().toString().trim().length() == 4) {
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Animation buttonz = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        buttonz.setDuration(3000);
        button2.startAnimation(buttonz);
    } else {


    }
```

It does not give any errors but it shows up when I open the activity but i dont want that i want it to happen when there is text in mSwitcher (Which is an EditText).

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: what do you mean by open the activity ?

Comment: according to your logic you are just checking if your string length is strictly equal to 4,not empty

Comment: Did you try to debug this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just checking if your EditText has string or not, why dont you use.

```
if(mSwitcher.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
....
...
}
```

More over it becomes

```
if (mSwitcher.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Animation buttonz = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        buttonz.setDuration(3000);
        button2.startAnimation(buttonz);
    } else {


    }
```

I do not recommend to use

```
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Animation buttonz = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

inside if statement.

BTW is `mSwitcher` an **EditText** ??

According to the known new requirement.

```
if(mSwitcher.getText().length()!=4)
{
    myButton.setEnabled(false);//change to your button name
}
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for the repy but it still gives me the button directly

Comment: what button ? I am sorry but you are not being clear.

Comment: the button that should take the user to the next activity, in that activity it searches through an api with the information that it has. so the ID is button2

Comment: are you trying to say that if the editext text is empty then the button should not be visible ?

Comment: yes, and when there are 4 characters in there it should be visible

Comment: ok, satisfy your condition and use myButton.setEnabled(false); to disable the button press